# Fatal Error that I can't solve-list

Tags: android, list, arraylist, hashmap

while I developing an android application I had an error:

```
"Unable to start activity Component Info :X . RunTimeExcepetion : your content must have a list . View whose ID  attribue is 'android.R.id.list'
```

I do have a list which is in `XML` file.

in java class it looks like:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

someone can help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got this in your xml file?

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're deriving from ListActivity.  To do that, your layout that you set via setContentView must have a ListView with an id of android.R.id.list.  Either derive from Activity instead of ListActivity or alter your layout.